# Bash script, get second to last day of the current month

Tags: bash, date, scripting

I would like to run a bash script that runs every day and checks the current date to see if it is the second to last day of the month and if it is do certain things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU date

```
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
next_to_last=$( date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) + 1 month - 2 days" +%Y-%m-%d )

if [[ $today == $next_to_last ]]; then
    echo "it is the 2nd last day of the month"
fi
```

The "inner" date call returns the current year and month and we hardcode "01" for the day => 
 the first day of this month. We add 1 month, then subtract 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this invocation:

```
date --date="$(date --date "next month" +'%Y-%m-01') -2 days"
```

Lets analyse the pieces:

1. outer layer: `date --date="$MAGIC -2 days"` if instead of `$MAGIC` we could get the first day of the next month, GNU date `--date` feature would help us: try it with `date --date="2016-08-01 -2 days"`
2. inner layer: instead of `$MAGIC` we use what is returned by `date --date "next month" +'%Y-%m-01'`: this gives us the first of the next month, again using the `--date` option of GNU date
3. you could either use two lines or use command substitution with `$( ... )`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have GNU date you could do something like:

```
set -- $(date "+%d %m %Y")
cal ${2} ${3} | nawk '{NF&&n=($NF-2)};END{exit(n==d)?0:1}' d=${1}
((!$?)) && echo "do certain things"
```